# Call number in England with no international-prefix on a phone with a German Sim

Tags: android

At the moment I receive a phone number from a the backend and use this in an intent so the user can call the number.

```
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        TaxiItemView taxiItemView = (TaxiItemView) view;
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + taxiItemView.getPhoneNumber()));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

I don't receive an international-pre-fix so what would happen in this case? If a user is in a different country than the sim in the phone, and then they dial a number without the international pre-fix. Does the phone take the prefix of the country it is in or does it use the pre-fix of the simcard?

Do I need to append the correct pre-fix on this number to ensure the correct number is called?

Comment: boom minus 3 in less than one minute. Any criticism is gladly excepted. I thought it was a reasonable question

Comment: You are getting downvoted because this isn't really a programming question. It sounds like a question about using a cell phone.

Comment: @Tanis.7x any better?

Comment: Yes that is much better. If I had a downvote to remove, I would remove it.

Comment: Sounds like a legitimate question to me. OP asks how to correctly dial number programmatically.

Comment: @Mighter I edited since

Comment: There is nothing you can do without a prefix or some other way of indicating the country.  If you tell the phone to dial "44123456789", it will call 0123456789 in the UK.  If you tell the phone to dial "0123456789" there is no way to determine that it is a UK number and will be dialed on whatever network the SIM is using.

Comment: Since this received three off-topic close votes *after* it was edited into a programming question, I'm voting to re-open the question.  And I almost *never* vote to re-open a question.

Comment: This is still primarily a non-programming question. How does a GSM telephone when roaming handle a telephone number without a "+" prefix? I'm not 100% sure, but I think it blindly uses the number as if it was a local number. Anyway, once you've determined the answer to _that_ question, by experimenting yourself or talking to your users or from other Internet sources, then you can turn this question into a pure programming question, with no need to talk about when and whether you need to modify the phone number. Just _how_ to modify the phone number.